# push iOS alert, and use presentviewcontroller in appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I created and app that receive a push notifications.

If the app is open, i put and alert with a button, when tapped the button I load a function, these function load a JSON with **Alamofire**, and I want to present other view controller:

```
var controller: UIViewController = (self.window?.rootViewController!.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewLoaded"))!
                let top: UIViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

But, I take these error:

> Attempt to present * on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy -

Any solution?, I don't use the `rootViewController = viewLoaded` because I need to controller the navigation.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to follow the StackOverflow [Format Guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so people who may want to assist you can understand your question better.

Comment: Thanks, sorry it is my first post. I know from the future ;)